#  MEF-based Settings Class

Tags: c#, wpf, mef, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn.Micro for an application and have a Settings class(Which de-/serializes to/from JSON).

Right now I have it centralized on a single ViewModel and pass it on to the other VMs. Would adding a Settings instance to MEF work in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can export your `Settings` class as a singleton adding the following attribute `[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]`
and then import it in your shared view model's constructor by decorating it with the `[ImportingConstructor]`attribute